# Cryptomania and NP $\cap$ co-NP

Tags: public-key, reference-request, complexity

Cryptomania is usually presented as the Impagliazzo's world, which gives us public-key cryptography under the assumption that trapdoor OWFs exist.
For purposes of constructing public-key cryptography we also want the underlying problem to be in $NP \cap coNP$ as described in [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52833/62415).
Are there any papers, which explore this particular requirement in relation to Impagliazzo's worlds?

Edit 02/04/2021: After some more digging I managed to find the answer, which describes the $NP \cap coNP$ requirement, as such I am restructuring this question, to only ask about results on impagliazzo's 5 worlds in relation to this property.

Comment: A classic machine solving a co-NP problem can trivially flip the result and solve the complementary NP problem.

Comment: i am aware of that, what i am curious about is whether the cryptomania results of constructing cryptosystems from trapdoor OWFs, also capture the intuition that the problems should be at the intersection of NP and co-NP and whether that intuition is correct.

Comment: I think this goes back to Brassard ([this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1056010) paper, behind a paywall unfortunately). It is conjectured that public-key cryptography corresponds to $\mathbf{SZK}\cap\mathbf{NP}$. You can read more about that [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/548).

Comment: I believe Brassard's paper is close enough to what I was looking for. If you want to turn it into an answer that would be nice. I might do that in a couple days if noone does, I have to process the details in the generalization section first though.

Comment: @fgrieu cryptomania is a name for possible resolution to P v NP Russell Impagliazzo coined along with 4 more and it's relatively standard in research papers on cryptography, it identifies a specific world with trapdoor owfs. changing it to cryptography does not make much sense.

Comment: @user4242: sorry for my mistake, you just taught me that meaning of "cryptomania", thanks. I knew cryptomania only as a pathological attraction for cryptocurrencies, otherwise weird things, or needlessly encrypting everything; or a newsletter devoted to the cult of cryptocurrencies.